# order while splitting (eg. TA should be split to two column "A" in first "T" second) in r

Tags: r, sorting, split, dataframe

I have following issue, I could solve:

```
set.seed (1234)
mydf <- data.frame (var1a = sample (c("TA", "AA", "TT"), 5, replace = TRUE),
                    varb2 = sample (c("GA", "AA", "GG"), 5, replace = TRUE),
                    varAB = sample (c("AC", "AA", "CC"), 5, replace = TRUE)
                    )
     mydf 

  var1a varb2 varAB
1    TA    AA    CC
2    AA    GA    AA
3    AA    GA    AC
4    AA    AA    CC
5    TT    AA    AC
```

I want to split two letter into different column, and then order alphabetically.

Edit: Ordering can be done before split, for example var1a value "TA" var1a should be "AT" or after split so that var1aa should be "A", and var1ab be "T" (instead of "T", "A"). 
so sorting is within each cell.

```
split_col <- function(.col, data){
    .x <- colsplit( data[[.col]], names =  paste0(.col, letters[1:2]))
   }
```

split each column and combine

```
    require(reshape)
    splitdf <- do.call(cbind, lapply(names(mydf), split_col, data = mydf))

 var1aa var1ab varb2a varb2b varABa varABb
1      T      A      A      A      C      C
2      A      A      G      A      A      A
3      A      A      G      A      A      C
4      A      A      A      A      C      C
5      T      T      A      A      A      C
```

But the unsolved part is I want to order the pair of columns such that columnname"a" and columname"b" are ordered, alphabetically. Thus expected output:

```
    var1aa var1ab varb2a varb2b varABa varABb
1      A      T      A      A      C      C
2      A      A      A      G      A      A
3      A      A      A      G      A      C
4      A      A      A      A      C      C
5      T      T      A      A      A      C
```

Can how can order (short with each pair of variable) ?

Comment: Do you mean that each row in each pair of columns needs to be ordered alphabetically? If that's the case, you should add that statement to your question because it's very unclear.

Comment: The question as it stands is incoherent. The dataframe created by the code does not match the example you offer. There are only 2 'T''s in the code data. Furthermore, the nature of the "order alphabetically" operation is unclear. Do you want to order by the the first column in reverese order

Comment: Your `split_col` function gives me an error: `Error in is.character(pattern) : 'pattern' is missing`

Comment: @sebastian-c Check that you're using the colsplit from reshape, not reshape2 or vice versa.

Comment: @joran yes, each pair of columns need to be orders - which can also be done before spliting than the case would be "TA" will be converted to "AT", but after splitting it is same but in pair of column will have "T" and "A", will be "A", "T", I am updating the question

Comment: @DWin I am updating the question for clarity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mylist <-as.list(mydf)

splits <- lapply(mylist, reshape::colsplit, names=c("a", "b"))
rowsort <- lapply(splits, function(x) t(apply(x, 1, sort)))
comb <- do.call(data.frame, rowsort)
comb

  var1a.1 var1a.2 varb2.1 varb2.2 varAB.a varAB.b
1       A       T       A       A       C       C
2       A       A       A       G       A       A
3       A       A       A       G       A       C
4       A       A       A       A       C       C
5       T       T       A       A       A       C
```

EDIT:
If names are important, you can replace them:

```
replaceNums <- function(x){
  .which <- regmatches(x, regexpr("[[:alnum:]]*(?=.)", x, perl=TRUE))
  stopifnot(length(x) %% 2 == 0) #checkstep
  paste0(.which, c("a", "b"))
}

names(comb) <- replaceNums(names(comb))
comb
  var1aa var1ab varb2a varb2b varABa varABb
1      A      T      A      A      C      C
2      A      A      A      G      A      A
3      A      A      A      G      A      C
4      A      A      A      A      C      C
5      T      T      A      A      A      C
```